# Spring - Loading a folder from project structure as a directory?

Tags: java, spring, directory

I have written an application using Spring. I have a package called "Services" that has a "Resources" folder. In that folder are a text file (file.txt) and a folder (write). I have managed to load the text file using the following lines of code:

```
 URL file = this.getClass().getResource("/file.txt");
 File myFile = new File(file.getFile())
```

However I am having opening the folder. The following does not seem to work:

```
 URL folder = this.getClass().getResource("/write");
```

Running the line about throws a NullPointerException. Can anyone suggest ways in which I can accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to end your string with "/".  The following may work:

```
URL folder = this.getClass().getResource("/write/");
```